# How to deal with the missing mod_perl.so when installing mod_perl 2.0.9 with apache 2.2.31 on Ubunt 14.04?

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl

I am trying to install mod_perl 2.0.9 with Apache 2.2.31 on Ubuntu 14.04. I got stuck with a missing file mod_perl.so. Below are the details.

Followed the instructions https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/install/install.html#Prerequisites,
I downloaded httpd-2.2.31.tar.gz and mod_perl-2.0.9.tar.gz.

I unziped them by

```
tar -xvzf httpd-2.2.31.tar.gz
tar -xvzf mod_perl-2.0.9.tar.gz
```

and got directories httpd-2.2.31 and mod_perl-2.0.9.

Then I typed command (following the link):

```
perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/path/to/httpd-2.2.31/server/mpm/prefork/bin/apxs
```

I got:

```
[warning] mod_perl dso library will be built as mod_perl.so
[warning] You'll need to add the following to httpd.conf:
[warning] 
[warning]   LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
[warning] 
[warning] depending on your build, mod_perl might not live in
[warning] the modules/ directory.

[warning] Check the results of
[warning] 
[warning]   $ /path/to/httpd-2.2.31/server/mpm/prefork/bin/apxs -q LIBEXECDIR
[warning] 
[warning] and adjust the LoadModule directive accordingly.
```

But, I could not find mod_perl.so anywhere.

Can anybody let me know where to get mod_perl.so or where it is supposed to be?

Without properly set mod_perl.so, I ran

```
make
```

and got

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [mod_perl.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/guohua/stas/mod_perl-2.0.9/src/modules/perl'
make: *** [modperl_lib] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu/debian, install libperl-dev which provides /usr/lib/libperl.so